# Default prompt for Zsh in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, zsh, prompt

How can you get the prompt "/home/user@address:/path" for Zsh?

I run the following unsuccessfully in my .zshrc

```
PROMPT='%d%>:%{\e[0m%} '
```

I get as my prompt

```
/home/masi
```

Comment: Your request is very confusing. how is /home/user@address:/path composed of parts that will update? /home/user is a path address is ... do you mean host? and /path is a path again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be give you what you want (*user*@*host*:*path*):

```
PROMPT=$'%n@%m:%d%{\e[0m%} '
```

If you wanted to limit the length of the path (`%>` from your example), you limit it to only display the last 12 characters like this:

```
PROMPT=$'%n@%m:%12<...<%d%<<%{\e[0m%} '
```

If you did not actually want the embedded escape code in there (it is a typical VT100-style command to clear any bold/etc. formatting), you could simplify it to this:

```
PROMPT='%n@%m:%12<...<%d%<< '
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the dollar sign before ' in your first two commands?

Comment: See the "Quoting" section of `man zshmisc`. It processes escape sequences. Try `echo '\e[0m'` and then again with the dollar sign. Pipe each one through `hd` to see the difference more clearly.

Comment: What is the purpose of piping the each one though `hd`? - It seems to give me hexadecimal output. If I increase the number of dollar signs in the order of two, then I get a different output.

Comment: Using `echo`, you only see a difference if the `BSD_ECHO` option is in effect. `echo '\e' | hd` shows the sequence `5c 65`; `echo $'\e' | hd` shows `1b`. Using `$'...'` is a way of making sure that the `\e` is always **<ESC>**, and not **<backslash>** + **e**. Really, see the `zshmisc(1)` under Quoting.

Answer (score 3):

In this case the [manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#SEC52) might be really helpful.

I'm guessing you want something like:
`PROMPT='$HOME@%M:%3~ '`

Apparently actually reading the 4 sentences in the short manual page is too much work. Maybe because it's a link:

```
13. Prompt Expansion

13.1 Expansion of Prompt Sequences

Prompt sequences undergo a special form of expansion.
This type of expansion is also available using the -P option
to the print builtin.

If the PROMPT_SUBST option is set, ...

Certain escape sequences may be recognised in the prompt string.

If the PROMPT_BANG option is set, ...

If the PROMPT_PERCENT option is set, ...

13.2 Simple Prompt Escapes

13.2.1 Special characters

%%
A `%'.

%)
A `)'.

13.2.2 Login information

%l
The line (tty) ...

%M
The full machine hostname.

%m
The hostname up to the first `.'. An integer may follow the `%' to specify
how many components of the hostname are desired. With a negative integer, 
trailing components of the hostname are shown.

%n
$USERNAME.

%y
The line (tty) ...

13.2.3 Shell state

%#
A `#' if the shell is running with privileges, ...

%?
The return status ...

%_
The status of the parser, ...

%d
%/
Present working directory ($PWD). If an integer follows the `%', it 
specifies a number of trailing components of $PWD to show; zero means 
the whole path. A negative integer specifies leading components, 
i.e. %-1d specifies the first component.

%~
As %d and %/, but if $PWD has a named directory as its prefix, that part
is replaced by a `~' followed by the name of the directory. If it starts
with $HOME, that part is replaced by a `~'.

%h
%!
Current history event number.

%i
The line number ...

%I
The line number ...

%j
The number of jobs.

%L
The current value of $SHLVL.

%N
The name of the script, ...

%x
The name of the file ...

%c
%.
%C
Trailing component ...These are deprecated... equivalent to %1~ and %1/ ...

13.2.4 Date and time ... Ignored ...

13.2.5 Visual effects ... Ignored ...

13.3 Conditional Substrings in Prompts ... Possibly useful but ignored ...
```

Comment: What is the purpose of ´3´ in ´%3~´? The command seems to work too without it.

Comment: It only shows the lowest three directory levels of the current directory (PWD). Try `cd /usr/share/doc/zsh` - the prompt will only show "share/doc/zsh"

Comment: You see that blue word that says "manual" there. It tells all about every possible variation. But, and I know this is a stretch, you have to click on it. With your mouse.